# docker-compose environment variable loading .env, but not env_file from compose file

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables

I don't really make sense of docker-compose's behavior with regards to environment variables files.

I've defined a few variables for an simple echo server setup with 2 flask application running.

In `.env`:

```
FLASK_RUN_PORT=5000
WEB_1_PORT=80
WEB_2_PORT=8001
```

Then in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

x-common-variables: &shared_envvars
  FLASK_ENV: development
  FLASK_APP: main.py
  FLASK_RUN_HOST: 0.0.0.0
  COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME: DOCKER_ECHOES

x-volumes: &com_volumes
  - .:/project          # maps the current directory, e.g. project root that is gitted, to /proj in the container so we can live-reload

services:
  web_1:
    env_file: .env
    build:
      dockerfile: dockerfile_flask
      context: .
    ports:
      - "${WEB_1_PORT}:${FLASK_RUN_PORT}"       # flask runs on 5000 (default). docker-compose --env-file .env up loads whatever env vars specified & allows them to be used this way here.
    volumes: *com_volumes
    environment:
      <<: *shared_envvars   # DRY: defined common stuff in a shared section above, & use YAML merge language syntaxe to include that k-v mapping here. pretty neat.
      FLASK_NAME: web_1
  web_2:
    env_file: .env
    build:
      dockerfile: dockerfile_flask
      context: .
    ports:
      - "${WEB_2_PORT}:${FLASK_RUN_PORT}"       # flask by default runs on 5000 so keep it on container, and :8001 on host
    volumes: *com_volumes
    environment:
      <<: *shared_envvars
      FLASK_NAME: web_2
```

If I run `docker-compose up` with the above, everything works as expected.

However, if I simply change the name of the file `.env` for, say, `flask.env`, and then accordingly change both `env_file: .env` to `env_file: flask.env`, then I get:

```
(venv) [fv@fv-hpz420workstation flask_echo_docker]$ docker-compose up
WARNING: The WEB_1_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The FLASK_RUN_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The WEB_2_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
```

So obviously the envvars defined in the file were not loaded in that case. I know that according to the documentation, the section `environement:`, which I am using, overrides what is loaded in the `env_file:`. But those aren't the same variables. And at any rate, if that was the issue, it shouldn't work either with the first way, right?

What's wrong with the above?

Comment: Try `env_file` with this [format](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option)

Comment: Same results. As I would expect since both are valid yaml notations... Would be nice if it had worked, but it still wouldn't explain why it didn't. I can already make it work (by naming my file simply .env) but I don't like not knowing the underlying issue...

Comment: You do nothing wrong. Check if there is a syntax error.

[LINK](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option)

Comment: Turns out there is indeed no syntax errors. My usage was wrong. It's all about WHEN each of those are loaded.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, the `env_file` is loaded AFTER the images have been built. We can verify this. With the code I have posted above, I can see that `env_file.env` has not been loaded at build time, because of the error message that I get (telling me `WEB_PORT_1` is not set etc.).

But this could simply be that the file is never loaded. To rule that out, we build the image (say by providing the missing arguments with `docker-compose build -e (...)`, then we can verify that it is indeed loaded (by logging its value in the flask application in my case, or a simple print to screen etc.).

This means the the content of `env_file` is available to the running container, but not before (such as when building the image).

If those variables are to be used within the `docker-compose.yml` file at BUILD time this file MUST be named `.env` (unless there is a way to provide a name other than the default, but if so I haven't found any). This is why changing  `env_file: flask.env` to `env_file: .env` SEEMED to make it work - but the real reason why it worked then was because my ports were specified in a `.env` with the default name that docker-compose parses anyways. It didn't care that I specified it in `docker-compose.yml` file or not.

***To summarize - TL;DR***

- If you need to feed environment variables to docker-compose for build-time, you must store them in a `.env`. No further actions needed, other than ensure this file is in the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml`. You can't change the default name `.env`
- To provide envars at container run-time, you can put them in `foo.env` and then specify `env_file:foo.env`.
- For run-time variable, another option is to specify them `environment: [vars]`, if just hard-coding them in the `docker-compose.yml` is acceptable.. According to doc (not tested) those will override any variables also defined by the `env_file`

Comment: vow this is horrible, docker should make them uniform, either make both work at build time or make both work at run time